# When to use “bei” and “zu” and when to omit?

Tags: grammar, verb, preposition

We could say as far as I know: “Hast du Geld bei dir?”. Here *bei* replies to the interrogative pronoun *wo*.

But in following statement I don’t understand why we need to use *abgeben* in conjunction with *bei* and *sagen* with *zu*. Does the verb *sagen* always require *zu* and does the verb *abgeben* always take the local preposition *bei?*

> Der Brief Ihres Nachbarn liegt in Ihrem Briefkasten. Sie geben ihn bei ihm ab. Was sagen Sie zu Ihrem Nachbarn?

Comment: *Wo geben Sie ihn ab? Bei ihm.* Same as your first sentence. You drop the letter *at* your neighbour's.

Comment: i think i don't step on him :-))

Comment: There is also _jemandem sagen_ without preposition.

Comment: @chirlu  And *jemandem etwas geben*, slightly different but could be applied, though.

Comment: Be careful, "bei" indicates a very general vicinity, not exactly in a place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Der Brief Ihres Nachbarn liegt in Ihrem Briefkasten.
>   The letter of your neighbor lays in your mailbox.

I hope the previous translation is clear.

> Sie geben ihn **bei ihm** ab.
>   You deliver it **at him**.

English is a foreign language to me, but I guess in English you normally would say:

> You deliver it **to** him.

But this is not the German way to talk about delivering a letter. In German you don't say to who you deliver a letter, but you say at which place you deliver it.

> **Wo** geben Sie ihn ab? - Sie geben ihn **bei ihm** ab.
>   **Where** do you deliver it? - You deliver it **at him**.

As you might have recognized *abgeben* (to deliver) is a separable verb, which will be spilt into »geben ... ab« in this sentence.

Now the last sentence:

> Was sagen Sie **zu** Ihrem Nachbarn?
>   What do you say **to** you neighbor?

Here »zu« (to) is just a normal preposition.

Comment: I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that "Was sagen Sie zu Ihrem Nachbarn" could also – in some contexts – mean "What do you say __about__ your neighbo[u]r".

Comment: @WalterTross: No. »What do you say **about** your neighbor« = »Was sagen Sie **über** Ihren Nachbarn.« Also pay attention to the case. In »*zu* Ihre**m** Nachbarn« you have to use dative case, in »*über* Ihre**n** Nachbarn« it is accusative.

Comment: @WalterTross, you are right, in the sense of “Tell me, what do you think about your neighbour?”

Comment: *Na, was sagt man dazu …*

Comment: Regarding the example with the letter delivery, is there still a discrepancy if one picks *zustellen*?

Comment: @Maasumi: Yes, there is a discrepancy. If a witness says in court "Ich habe ihm den Brief zugestellt", someone might ask: "Haben Sie wirklich *ihm* den Brief zugestellt oder haben Sie den Brief *bei ihm* zugestellt? Er behauptet, er hätte ihn nicht bekommen, weil sein Briefkasten aufgebrochen wurde." To which the witness might reply: "Ich habe den Brief *zu* ihm zugestellt. Damit will ich sagen: Weil er sich geweigert hat, den Brief anzunehmen, habe ich ihn seiner Tochter gegeben, die neben ihm stand. Die hat ihn dann auf seine Anweisung in den Briefkasten geworfen."

Comment: @HansAdler *Zu ihm zugestellt* and *bei ihm zugestellt* sound very unnatural if not wrong. Also, "discrepancy" was referring to *to* having to be translated as *bei* in this case, since "one doesn't say *to whom* one delivers the letter to", which I am not convinced of just yet.

Comment: @Maasumi: There are hundreds of Google hits for "bei mir zugestellt". This is perfectly standard. "Zu jemandem zustellen" is unusual (though still plenty of Google hits for "zu mir zugestellt") because *zustellen* usually implies that the object has arrived, whereas *zu* (besides sounding redundant) stresses the direction. There is rarely use for this combination, so I had to construct a special context.

Comment: @HansAdler Yeah, it's alright I guess. Anyway, that was not my main point.

Comment: I am afraid I still may not fully understand your main point. If it's about the apparent duplication of *zu* and the duplication of *to* in your English sentence was actually intentional - that's not an accurate translation. *Zustellen* means *deliver*, not *deliver to*. Yes, German speakers feel that there is some sort of duplication between the *zu* in *zustellen* and the second one, and this slightly discourages the use of *zu jemandem zustellen*. But it's not a proper duplication, and so it's not a very important factor. Even in English you can "offload something off a lorry".

Comment: @HansAdler My maint point is that in German, you *can* express *to whom* a letter is delivered to (the opposite of which is stated in the answer), namely by choosing *jemandem einen Brief zustellen*. BTW, it's only by accident that read your response, as you didn't ping me.

Comment: @Maasumi: Oh, I see. Yes, that part seems to be wrong. It appears Hubert Schölnast forgot to consider *zustellen*

Answer (score 2):

Both German and English can be very precise about the details of an interaction, though English partially lost one option (indirect object rather than preposition) as a consequence of the loss of case distinctions. What differs occasionally is the details -- especially the unmarked, default point of view adopted when we don't care about the details:

- Den Brief *bei*m Nachbarn abgeben. - Deliver the letter *at* the neighbour's [place]. We don't care whether anyone is at home and the letter is handed over to the neighbour or his dog, or whether it's deposited in his letterbox. This is the default point of view in German. It covers all cases.
- Den Brief *zu*m Nachbarn abgeben. - Deliver the letter *to* the neighbour in order to get rid of it. (Rarely used. Normally one would prefer "Den Brief *an* den Nachbarn abgeben.)
- Den Brief dem Nachbarn abgeben. - Deliver the neighbour the letter. (Not too long ago sentence structures like this were unremarkable in English, but it's pretty much obsolete nowadays. So you now have to use the same translation as for the previous sentence instead.) The use of *abgeben* rather than *geben* is unusual and suggests a less straightforward reading such as giving a specific letter from a larger collection to the neighbour so he doesn't go away empty-handed.

Example:

> Ich habe noch nie einen Brief beim Nachbarn abgegeben. Warum auch? Wir können doch einfach miteinander sprechen. Aber nachdem ich heute wieder eine Ladung Kettenbriefe bekommen habe, habe ich ein paar davon dem Nachbarn abgegeben. Es ist anstrengend, alle Forderungen in den Kettenbriefen zu erfüllen, um nicht verflucht zu werden. Da ist es eine Entlastung, wenn ich einige davon zum (an den) Nachbarn abgeben kann.

---

- Etwas *bei*m Nachbarn sagen. - Say/tell something *at* the neighbour's place.
- Etwas *zu*m Nachbarn sagen. - Say/tell something *to* the neighbour. One of two standard ways of expressing this in German; preferred when the speech act and the identity of the addressee are more important than the passing of the message. Roughly means: Address the neighbour with something.
- Dem Nachbarn etwas sagen. - Tell the neighbour something. The other standard way of expressing this in German; preferred when the passing of the message is most important and the details of the communication act don't matter.

Example:

> Sag dem Nachbarn, dass er ein Idiot ist. Aber sag dabei nicht "du" zum Nachbarn. Und sag es vor allem nicht beim Nachbarn (denn da würde ihm seine Frau helfen, dich zu verprügeln), sondern sag es bei uns zu Hause.