# Einen Brief zustellen

Tags: meaning, preposition

In den [Kommentaren](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26035/when-to-use-bei-and-zu-and-when-to-omit/26039?noredirect=1#comment62311_26039) zu einer [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26035/when-to-use-bei-and-zu-and-when-to-omit/26039#26039) auf eine andere [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26035/when-to-use-bei-and-zu-and-when-to-omit) hier auf German-SE hat sich eine Diskussion rund um die möglichen Präpositionen ergeben, die man verwenden kann, wenn ein Brief zugestellt wird.

Dass folgender Satz korrekt ist, scheint außer Streit zu stehen:

> Der Briefträger stellt einen Brief zu.

Unstimmigkeit herrscht darüber, wie unter Verwendung des Wortes »*zustellen*« zu formulieren ist, dass ein Brief an eine bestimmte Person abgegeben wurde, oder dass er an einem bestimmten Ort abgegeben wurde.

Zur Diskussion stehen:

**Zustellung an eine Person**

> 1. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **dem Sekretär** zu. (wem? Dativ)
> 2. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **an den Sekretär** zu. (wohin? »an« + Akkusativ)
> 3. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **bei dem Sekretär** zu. (wo? »bei« + Dativ)

**Zustellung an einen Ort**

> 4. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **der Kanzlei** zu. (wem? Dativ)
> 5. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **an die Kanzlei** zu. (wohin? »an« + Akkusativ)
> 6. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **an der Kanzlei** zu. (wo? »an« + Dativ)
> 7. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief **bei der Kanzlei** zu. (wo? »bei« + Dativ)

Die Fragen lauten:
Welche dieser Formulierungen sind korrekt? Wie sind sie stilistisch zu bewerten? Inwiefern unterscheiden sie sich hinsichtlich ihrer Bedeutungen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Nachdem du mir die Möglichkeit aufgezeigt hast, dies wollen zu können, habe ich mich dafür entschieden diese Möglichkeit in Erwägung zu ziehen. Ich stellte fest, dass du recht hast: Unter bestimmten Umständen ist es tatsächlich möglich, das zu wollen. Und da diese Umstände vorlagen, wollte ich es tatsächlich. Und weil ich zufällig auch nicht zu faul dazu war, setzte ich meinen eigenen Willen auch durch und ließ dem Wunsch die Tat folgen. Und das gleich ordentlich. Wenn schon, denn schon. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ohne zweites Objekt**

Es dürfte Einigkeit darüber bestehen, dass man das Verb *zustellen* in der beabsichtigten Bedeutung ohne Dativobjekt (aber mit einem Akkusativobjekt) verwenden kann:

> Der Briefträger stellt einen Brief zu.

**Mit Dativobjekt**

Ebenso klar ist, dass man den Empfänger mit einem zusätzlichen Dativobjekt ausdrücken kann:

> Der Briefträger stellt einen Brief dem Empfänger zu.
>   Der Briefträger stellt dem Empfänger einen Brief zu.

(Im Zweifelsfall trägt das zuletzt genannte Objekt eher die Betonung. Wenn ich betonen will, dass der Briefträger den Brief dem Empfänger und nicht dem Bürgermeister zustellt, wähle ich eher die erste Variante. Wenn ich betonen will, dass er dem Empfänger einen Brief und keine Torte zustellt, wähle ich eher die zweite. Diese Präferenz kann aber immer aufgehoben werden, indem man das erste Objekt betont. Wenn ich gar nichts betonen will, ist die Reihenfolge egal.)

**Mit adverbialer Bestimmung oder Präpositionalobjekt**

[PS: Hier wird es etwas ausführlicher als nötig - ursprünglich, um eine inzwischen gelöschte falsche Antwort zu widerlegen.]

Das schließt natürlich nicht aus, dass es noch andere Möglichkeiten gibt, den Empfänger anzugeben. Für die Fragestellung relevante Möglichkeiten sind Präpositionalobjekt sowie adverbiale Bestimmung (wenn sie ebenfalls mit einer Präposition beginnt). (Das und die folgende Darstellung ist eine Vereinfachung, weil es mit sämtlichen feinsinnigen Unterscheidungen, die man treffen kann, absurd kompliziert würde. Für die Details, siehe Wikipedia.)

Eine adverbiale Bestimmung ist eine Angabe von Details, die jedem beliebigen Verb hinzugefügt werden kann, solange es semantisch Sinn ergibt. Drei typische Beispiele: *laut pfeifend*, *nachts* und *im Wald*. Man kann sie auch kombinieren, wobei je nach Sinn u.U. auch Konjunktionen angebracht sind. Durch die Position kann man subtile Bedeutungsunterschiede andeuten. Beispiel:

> Der Briefträger stellt nachts im Wald Briefe zu.
>   Der Briefträger stellt Briefe nachts im Wald zu.
>   Der Briefträger stellt Briefe im Wald nachts zu.

Bei der ersten Formulierung vermutet man, dass ein gelegentliches exzentrisches Verhalten beschrieben wird. Bei der zweiten klingt es, als würde er womöglich tagsüber oder in der Stadt gar keine Briefe zustellen. Bei der dritten Variante ist die nächtliche Zustellung vielleicht eine Besonderheit, die nur für Waldbriefe gilt.

**.. z.B. adverbiale Bestimmung des Orts mit *bei* oder *an***

Ein Beispiel für eine hier relevante adverbiale Bestimmung ist *beim Briefempfänger*. Beispiele:

> Der Briefträger trinkt beim Briefempfänger Kaffee.
>   Der Briefträger trinkt Kaffee beim Briefempfänger.
>   Der Briefträger legt beim Briefempfänger Feuer.
>   Der Briefträger legt Feuer beim Briefempfänger.
>   Der Briefträger stellt beim Briefempfänger Schilder auf.
>   Der Briefträger stellt beim Briefempfänger Briefe zu.
>   Der Briefträger stellt beim Briefempfänger den Brief zu.
>   Der Briefträger stellt den Brief beim Briefempfänger zu.

Man kann (natürlich) zu jedem dieser Beispiele fragen, *bei wem* der Briefträger es tut. Man kann aber auch allgemein fragen, *wo* er es tut. Daran erkennt man, dass *beim Briefempfänger* in jedem der bisherigen Fälle tatsächlich eine adverbiale Bestimmung (des Orts) ist. Bei einem Präpositionalobjekt geht das nämlich nicht:

> Der Briefträger macht sich beim Briefempfänger unmöglich.
>   Der Briefträger tritt beim Briefempfänger ins Fettnäpfchen.

Falls der Briefträger in der Wohnung des Briefempfängers versehentlich bei einem Tête-à-Tête den BH von dessen Ehefrau anzündet, kann man mit *bei wem?* oder *wo?* fragen und es handelt sich um eine adverbiale Bestimmung. Falls der Briefträger aber im Postamt versehentlich den Briefempfänger mit Kaffee übergießt, dann muss man den Briefempfänger mit *bei wem?* erfragen und es handelt sich um ein Präpositionalobjekt. Allgemeine Fragen wie *wo?*, in denen die Präposition nicht vorkommt, sind bei Präpositionalobjekten nicht möglich. (Natürlich gibt es häufig Grenzfälle, in denen Ort und Empfänger des Unmöglichmachens gleichzeitig gemeint sind. Solche Mehrdeutigkeiten machen die Sprache lebendig.)

Damit ist auch klar, dass es sich bei *an* + Dativ ebenfalls um eine adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes handelt:

> Der Briefträger stellt den Brief an der Kanzlei zu.

Wenn man hier fragt "An was stellt er den Brief zu?", bekommt man eine Antwort mit *an* + Akkusativ. Dazu siehe den nächsten Abschnitt. Jedenfalls müssen wir in diesem Fall entweder mit *an wem oder was?* den Kasus präzisieren oder gleich allgemein *wo?* fragen. Da letzteres überhaupt möglich ist, handelt es sich auch hier um eine adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes. In Verbindung mit *Kanzlei* ist es aus semantischen Gründen etwas auffällig, aber mit einem anderen Substantiv und im passenden Kontext wird es ganz unauffällig:

> Der Briefträger stellt dem flüchtigen Briefempfänger den Brief am Ufer zu.

**.. z.B. Zielangabe mit *an* oder *zu***

Ich hab leider kein deutsches Online-Wörterbuch gefunden, das die Präpositionalobjekte jedes Verbs vollständig auflistet. Es ist aber völlig klar, dass *zustellen* von Muttersprachlern (und gerade auch Postdienstleistungsunternehmen) sehr häufig in Verbindung mit *an* + Akkusativ, daneben gelegentlich aber auch mit *zu* + Dativ verwendet wird. Dabei zeichnet sich aber ein ganz erheblicher Unterschied ab zwischen der modernen Gebrauchs- und Umgangssprache, wie man sie im Webkorpus von Google findet, und der [gedruckten Sprache laut Googles n-gram-Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dem+Empf%C3%A4nger+zugestellt%2Can+den+Empf%C3%A4nger+zugestellt%2Czum+Empf%C3%A4nger+zugestellt&year_start=1800&corpus=20), die beide Varianten gar nicht kennt. (Google Books hat immerhin 26 Treffer in Büchern für "an den Empfänger zugestellt". Das war zu wenig, um bei den n-Grammen berücksichtigt zu werden, zumal viele davon auch erst nach 'Redaktionsschluss' gedruckt wurden.) Die Ergebnisse der Google-Suchen kann sich jeder selber anschauen, um sich ein Bild zu machen:

- ["dem Empfänger zugestellt"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dem+Empf%C3%A4nger+zugestellt%22)
- ["an den Empfänger zugestellt"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+den+Empf%C3%A4nger+zugestellt%22)
- ["zum Empfänger zugestellt"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zum+Empf%C3%A4nger+zugestellt%22)

Ich würde es etwa so zusammenfassen: Der Empfänger wird überwiegend mit einem Dativobjekt angegeben. Daneben wird der Empfänger aber auch häufig mit *an* angegeben; offenbar vor allem in bürokratisch geprägter Sprache. Die Angabe mit *zu* kommt nur selten und dann offenbar eher in der Umgangssprache vor.

Mein persönliches Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass die Angabe mit *an* völlig synonym mit der durch ein Dativobjekt ist. Sie klingt etwas formell, aber auch etwas moderner. Die Angabe mit *zu* entsteht für mein Gefühl entweder als Übersetzungsfehler (aus dem Englischen, von *deliver to*), oder aus dem Bedürfnis heraus, das als etwas altmodisch empfundene Dativobjekt ebenso zu vermeiden wie das bürokratische *an*. (Die beiden Beweggründe überschneiden und beeinflussen sich sicher.) Die Angabe mit *zu* + Dativ klingt für mich an Richtungsbestimmungen wie die folgende an:

> Der Briefträger wirft den Ball zum Briefempfänger.

Dadurch kann man evt. einen feinen Unterschied andeuten. Dieser Anklang ist nämlich in *zustellen* (wo er sicher ursprünglich auch vorhanden war) weitgehend verloren und durch eine juristische Definition überdeckt, wonach ein Brief dem Empfänger zugestellt ist, wenn er z.B. in dessen Briefkasten liegt. (Auch dann, wenn der Empfänger gerade für ein halbes Jahr in Australien im Urlaub ist.) Das gilt sowohl für die Verwendung mit Dativobjekt als auch die mit *an* + Akkusativ. Dagegen ist die Verwendung mit *zu* + Dativ relativ neu; ihre präzise Bedeutung muss also in jedem Fall je nach Kontext und Anklängen an ähnliche Formulierungen neu ausgehandelt werden, wobei auch die Abgrenzung zu anderen Formulierungen eine Rolle spielen kann. Letzteres bedeutet, dass es eine Tendenz gibt, *zustellen zu* + Dativ so zu interpretieren, dass es gerade nicht 100% synonym zu *zustellen* + Dativobjekt oder *zustellen an* + Akkusativ ist.

Jedenfalls sind folgende Varianten zumindest nicht falsch:

> Der Briefträger stellt einen Brief an den Briefempfänger zu.
>   Der Briefträger stellt einen Brief zum Briefempfänger zu.

Die zweite ist allerdings umgangssprachlich oder kreativer Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 4):

Man kann unterscheiden, wer der Adressat ist, und wer den Brief entgegennimmt. In einfachen Fällen sind beide Personen identisch, und wenn es auf den Unterschied nicht ankommt, oder der Kontext Missverständnisse ausschließt, sind alle Formen möglich:

1. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief dem Sekretär zu. (wem? Dativ)
2. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief an den Sekretär zu. (wohin? »an« + Akkusativ)
3. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief bei dem Sekretär zu. (wo? »bei« + Dativ)

Der Brief kann aber bei 1. und 3. an den Geschäftsführer adressiert sein. Im Fall 2 wohl nicht - es ist ein Brief an den Sekretär.

4. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief der Kanzlei zu. (wem? Dativ)
5. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief an die Kanzlei zu. (wohin? »an« + Akkusativ)
6. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief an der Kanzlei zu. (wo? »an« + Dativ)
7. Der Briefträger stellte den Brief bei der Kanzlei zu. (wo? »bei« + Dativ)

In 4. geht der Brief wohl an jemanden von der Kanzlei. In 5. ist es ein Brief an die Kanzlei, an der auch Privatbriefe an den Notar ankommen könnten, oder die treuhänderisch Briefe für Dritte entgegennehmen kann. Aber in 5. ist der Adressat die Kanzlei selbst. 
In 6. und 7. ist die unmittelbar räumliche Nähe der Kanzlei angesprochen, nicht die Kanzlei selbst. Empfänger ist vielleicht sonstwer, vielleicht aber auch wer von der Kanzlei, der gerade kommt oder geht oder vor der Kanzlei steht und eine raucht.